# How to write test case for UIViewAnimation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, tdd, testcase

I want to write test case for animation block.

```
-(void)removeFooter {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (!self.loadMoreDelegate) {
            self.tableFooterView = nil;
        }
    }];
}
```

in test case need to  check the tablefooterview, but **self.tableFooterView = nil;** execute after some time in completion block while test case run before it. Please tell me how to write test case for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the "test case" method from the competition block

Keep in mind that it will be usually executed in that thread.

But if you want to execute it in the main one you can simply call the method in this way:

```
-(void)removeFooter {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (!self.loadMoreDelegate) {
            self.tableFooterView = nil;
        }
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }];
}
```

Comment: but not work. i wrote following code
-(void)testloadMoreDelegate {
    self.tableView.loadMoreDelegate = self;
    XCTAssert(self.tableView.tableFooterView, @"footer should be initialized");
    
    [self.tableView setLoadMoreDelegate:nil];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(checkTableFooter) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

}

-(void)checkTableFooter {
    XCTAssertNil(self.tableView.tableFooterView, @"footer should be initialized");

}

Comment: this code is really different from the one you write in the question;
What you want to achieve?

Comment: I try to explain you. Your completion block is executed asynchronously. That means that, in your code, you create the animation and start it, but the code inside the animation will be executed in another thread, and so the competition block, after 0.3 seconds (as you set it)... but the application doesn't wait the execution of the animation for 0.3 second; it will go on with the other operation executing the rest of the code... I guess you should read some more information about multi thread  concepts

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. 
   Execute the task in anthor thread and and sleep the main thread till task completion.

```
 NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
       // task which take time to execute 
        self.tableView.refreshDelegate = self;
        [self.tableView failedToRefreshWithMessage:@"test message"];
    }];
    sleep(2.5); // greater than task completion time
    XCTAssertFalse(self.tableView.isPullToRefresh,@"refresh control not stop.");
```